# Regex to replace tags spawn in multiple lines

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create utility for me that converts word documents to clean HTML but stuck on cleaning tags that spawn on multiple lines. I can share the link if someone wants to look the tool online but I don't want this post to be marked as spam.

[image]

I want to replace <p>..<strong> and </p>...</strong> with one tag using php or javascript.

I've used HTML Tidy.

```
function cleaning($string, $tidyConfig = null) 
{
    $out = array ();
    $config = array (
            'indent' => true,
            'show-body-only' => false,
            'clean' => true,
            'output-xhtml' => true,
            'preserve-entities' => true 
    );
    if ($tidyConfig == null) {
        $tidyConfig = &$config;
    }
    $tidy = new tidy ();
    $out ['full'] = $tidy->repairString ( $string, $tidyConfig, 'UTF8' );
    unset ( $tidy );
    unset ( $tidyConfig );
    $out ['body'] = preg_replace ( "/.*<body[^>]*>|<\/body>.*/si", "", $out ['full'] );
    $out ['style'] = '<style type="text/css">' . preg_replace ( "/.*<style[^>]*>|<\/style>.*/si", "", $out ['full'] ) . '</style>';
    return ($out);
}
```

Comment: What is the regex you have tried ?

Comment: Replace it with what tag? As if you replace it with `<strong>` everything will have that style including the ampersand which doesn't have it in the original. And that could be a problem for future elements that have more content than just an ampersand. If you just use `<p>` then you lose all the styling of `<strong>` all together

Comment: I have used htmltidy, check the edit. Thanks

Comment: What about the other tags on the image you provided ? What is the expected output ?

Comment: I want to move on one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it is not very clear at all what you desired outcome should be, based on your sample code.

For example, what exactly would you convert the following to, and why (as it is valid HTML code)?

```
<p>
    <strong>Minify</strong>&nbsp;<strong>CSSis
    all free</strong>
</p>
<p>
```

You could use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to convert the sample to the following with `strip_tags($text,'<p>')`:

```
<p>
    Minify&nbsp;CSSis
    all free
</p>
<p>
```

Or with `strip_tags($text,'<strong>')`:

```
    <strong>Minify</strong>&nbsp;<strong>CSSis
    all free</strong>
```

A combination of `trim()` and `str_replace()` could clean it up further to single line with something like:

```
function cleanText($str,$keep) {
    $str = trim(strip_tags($str,$keep));
    return str_replace(array("\r\n","\n","\r","\t"),' ',$str);
}
```

Highly suggest you update your question for clarity and desired end result.